# NextJS Script with 'beforeInteractive' strategy triggers position error

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to embed hubspot to my static website.

I put this in the root layout:

```
<html lang={'it'}>
  <Script src="https://js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js" strategy='beforeInteractive'/>
  <body>...</body>
</html>
```

that renders the script tag just before the `<head>` tag closure:

`<script src="https://js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js"></script>`

as expected. When running on browser, nextjs triggers this error on console:

> Warning: Cannot render a sync or defer  outside the main document without knowing its order. Try adding async="" or moving it into the root  tag.

that I cannot really understand. The tag is already in the `<head>` section, so what's wrong with that?